# Enum with array/list values

Tags: java, enums

```
if (isProductDeliverable) {
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = Arrays.asList(new String[] { Fields.NAME, Fields.EMAIL, Fields.ADDRESS });
} else {
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = Arrays.asList(new String[] { Fields.NAME, Fields.EMAIL });
}
```

Instead of this, I want to have a predefined enum with two fields - `REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_DELIVERABLE_PRODUCTS` and `REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_DOWNLOADABLE_PRODUCTS`

I know the theory of enums but I've never used them so I cant figure out a way how to do this.

Or maybe a way to ask for the required fields by passing this "isProductDeliverable" boolean and get the correct array of fields?

Comment: Did you look at the [recommended tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)?

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? Note that it's unconventional to have a variable with a shouty name like REQUIRED_FIELDS...

Comment: Yes I've seen the tutorial but I dont know how to apply it in this particular case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enums can have data and behaviour much like classes. Something like this should work...

```
public enum RequiredFields {
    REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_DELIVERABLE_PRODUCTS( Fields.NAME, Fields.EMAIL, Fields.ADDRESS ),
    REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_DOWNLOADABLE_PRODUCTS( Fields.NAME, Fields.EMAIL );

    private List<String> fields;
    private RequiredFields(String... fields){
        this.fields = Arrays.asList(fields);
    }
    public List<String> getFields(){
        return fields;
    }
}
```

Further improvement:

In above code, the `fields` property is still mutable. Someone could do `REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_DELIVERABLE_PRODUCTS.getFields().add(..)` which would beat the whole purpose of having the `enum` in the first place.

Better implementation for the constructor would be:

```
private RequiredFields(String... fields){
    this.fields = ImmutableList.copyOf(fields); //com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
}
```

Comment: So whenever I need the list of fields, I just do REQUIRED_FIELDS_FOR_DOWNLOADABLE_PRODUCTS.getFields(), right? Is there a way to pass "isDeliverable" to the enum so that it returns the correct type, so I can avoid an if else construct?

Comment: 'Which enum to return' logic is probably better kept outside the enum, in the class where you are using the enum.

Comment: Ok but is it at least possible?

Comment: Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(fields)) works too and has no external dependencies.

Comment: @J.K. Enum is very similar to a standard class, you can just add a static method with an if/else.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

For creating immutable list of objects, from Java 9 you can use List.of static method. So you can create something like:

```
   Enum1("a","b"),
   Enum2("c","d")
   private String fields;
   EnumClassName(String...args) {
    this.fields = List.of(args);
   }
  }
```

In the calling method you can call like
`list = Enum1.fields;`
Hoping this clears your understanding.